# Subtract interval from Date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do something like `CURRENT_DATE-number_of_days`, which should return a date in format yyyy-MM-dd. Is this possible with Oracle database queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SYSDATE` (oracle specific) or `CURRENT_DATE` (ANSI) to get the current date/time.

In SQL Developer you can set the date format by going to "Tools" > "Preferences" and selecting the "Database" > "NLS" on the left hand side and then editing the Date Format.

If you want to use a different date format most of the time but in this singular instance want the date in ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD) then you can use `TO_CHAR( date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` (but it will then return as a string rather than a date).

To add (subtract) days from a date then you can do one of several options (note: SQLFIDDLE has different NLS date formatting perameters on its output that you've specified, but it should give you the idea):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/6473)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' DAY,
       CURRENT_DATE - 1
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/6473/0)**:

```
| CURRENT_DATE-INTERVAL'1'DAY |             CURRENT_DATE-1 |
|-----------------------------|----------------------------|
|  November, 12 2015 12:28:40 | November, 12 2015 12:28:40 |
```

Comment: Minor difference between `SYSDATE` and `CURRENT_DATE` is: `SYSDATE` returns current date (+time) in database server time zone, `CURRENT_DATE` returns current date in current session time zone.